# Django - return list of children from values() function?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, django-views

I'm building a Django app and trying to return a list of objects inside of my `values()` dict.
My sample models look like this -

```
class State(models.Model):
    StateID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    StateName = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='State Name')
    StateAbbreviation = models.CharField(max_length = 4, default='SN')

    Population = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    NationID = models.ForeignKey(Nation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



class City(models.Model):
    CityID = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    CityName = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default='City Name')

    Population = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    StateID = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I would like to return is something along the lines of :

```
[{
   'StateName': 'California'
 , 'NationID__NationName': 'United States'
 , 'Population': 90000000
 , 'CityList': [{'CityName': 'Los Angeles', 'Population': 4000000},{'CityName': 'San Francisco', 'Population': 2000000}, ...more cities]
}, {
   'StateName': 'Texas'
 , 'NationID__NationName': 'United States'
 , 'Population': 50000000
 , 'CityList': [{'CityName': 'Austin', 'Population': 1000000},{'CityName': 'Dallas', 'Population': 2000000}, ...more cities]
}, 
...more states
]
```

Now, I would love to use the query below, but it of course doesn't work as I can't figure out how to return a list into a `values()` return object. Is this possible?

```
StateList = State.objects.values('StateName', 'NationID__NationName', 'Population').annotate(
        CityList = City.objects.values('CityName', 'Population')
    )
```

I know I could do something like the query below, but the state info (state name, nation name, state population) would be copied over every city.

```
StateList = State.objects.values('StateName', 'NationID__NationName', 'Population', 'city__CityName', 'city__Population')
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you need the result to be in that format? What are you doing with the result?

Comment: I would love to display them using a template with the state info as the header on a table, and cities listed with info. The actual implementation will include more fields than city name & pop.  By having the list of cities nested under a state, it will allow for much easier looping in a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Query doesn't provide output like your expected output. It rather provides flat output. So, I would love to do as following:

```
       from itertools import groupby
       cities = City.objects.values('StateID', 'Population', 'CityName')
       city_groups = {state: list(cities) for state, cities in groupby(cities, key=lambda x: x['StateID'])}
       states = State.objects.values('StateID', 'StateName', 'NationID__NationName', 'Population') 
       for state in states:
            state['cities'] = city_groups[state['StateID'])]
       print(states)
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan, I believe your solution is my best bet at this point, implementing an approach with a for loop & matching.

Comment: Yah, happy to help you.